# In JMeter how do I set multiple dynamic variables in User Parameters or CSV Data Set Config

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Very new to JMeter (and a long time Stack Overflow listener but first time caller so take it easy on me) so any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to set up a JMeter test that uses multiple dynamically generated access tokens to run across scenarios. I currently have a set of data using the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) containing login credentials of a user's email and password for example:

```
email1@email.com,password1
email2@email.com,password2
```

Next I send a [HTTP POST request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to the Login service which generates an accessToken. Then, I am using the [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to grab the generated accessToken. After that I am using the [BeanShell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) to store the accessToken property/variable.

My issue seems to lie here in this last step since it will only store the last generated variable instead of each of the generated accessTokens. I want to be able to store/overwrite the grabbed accessToken for each email password combination. I would like it to modify/populate the CSV file like this:

```
email1@email.com,password1,accessToken1
email2@email.com,password2,accessToken2
```

I have also tried using the [Pre Processor > User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)

[Screen shot of User Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iduZH.png)

I would like to have the "userBearerToken" variable update/overwrite along with the tests, but I cannot find a way to do so or if this can even currently be done.

I'm finding it difficult to word what I am trying to ask, but basically I want to store multiple dynamically generated variables (accessTokens that change and time out) and use them in other tests. I don't care which component can handle this (either the CSV or User Parameter), but I need to be able to store these variables with their corresponding email password credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the `accessToken` value into a JMeter property for using in other [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) be aware that properties are global for the whole JVM and remain until JMeter is restarted so if you define a single `accessToken` property - each JMeter Thread (or iteration) will overwrite the value.

The solution is to use current thread (or iteration) number as prefix or postfix, this can be done using either [__${__threadNum} function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) or relevant JMeter Variable depending on how iteration is defined or both.

Example setup:

1. In first thread group: `${__setProperty(access_token_${__threadNum},bar,)}`
2. In second thread group: `${__P(access_token_${__threadNum},)}`

Demo:

[image]

---

If you want to save the values into a file writing into the current one is not the best idea as you can (and most probably will) get malformed file due to a form of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). So I would recommend using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property instead.

If you add the next line to *user.properties* file:

sample_variables=email,password,accessToken

JMeter will store the variables named `${email}`, `${password}`, and `${accessToken}` along with their values in the .jtl results file which is basically CSV file which can be re-used anywhere else.

However if you have a requirement to store only the credentials and the token you can go for the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) plugin and configure it to save the aforementioned variables values into a separate file, the relevant configuration would be as simple as:

```
variable#0,variable#1,variable#2
```

[image]

You can install Flexible File Writer plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T for the answer. I ended up using the Flexible File Writer plugin to solve this issue.